# FFMPEG working in terminal, but not in php script

Tags: php, ffmpeg, command-line, video-conversion

I want to allow users to upload videos, and automatically convert them to mp4. I have tested 'ffmpeg' on the terminal, and it works perfectly. However, I cannot get it to work with my php script, which is as follows:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = 'uploadvideo/';
$file_name = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$db_file_name = date("DMjGisY")."".rand(100000,999999);
$uploaded_file = $uploads_dir . $file_name;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaded_file)) {
    $ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';
    
    // MP4
    $video_mp4 = $db_file_name . '.mp4';
    exec($ffmpeg . ' -i "' . $uploaded_file . '" -c:v libx264 "./uploadvideo/' . $video_mp4 . '" -y 1>convert.txt 2>&1');
    
    $vidmp4 = 'uploadvideo/'.$video_mp4.'';
```

The rest of the script is echos, depending on whether or not the conversions is successful. I haven't even gotten to this. The variable, '$db_file_name' is used to make the filenames unique, because we anticipate a lot of video uploads. I think there is something wrong with the path for 'ffmpeg' or, the 'exec()' command. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Maybe try using absolute paths. I personally had problems with relative ones when launched via php `exec` and absolutes fixed the problem.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Does ffmpeg even get executed? If it does, what does the console output from ffmpeg say? If you don't know how to get that then add the `-report` option and look for a file named like `ffmpeg-20211101-100057.log` in the working directory.

Comment: No, ffmpeg is not getting executed. No matter what I've tried, all I get is a screen with a blank video, or, a square where the video should be. However, it does upload the original file. It just won't convert and upload the converted file. I can't find the file, ffmpeg-20211101-100057.log anywhere.

Comment: I ran the command, 'locate ffmpeg-20211101-100057.log' and the file does not exist.

Comment: It won't be named exactly `ffmpeg-20211101-100057.log`. Name structure is `ffmpeg-date-time.log`, so the file name depends on when you ran ffmpeg (assuming ffmpeg even ran). Are you not getting any PHP errors?

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors. I just get a blank screen because nothing is working.